# How to convert svg icon to font in angular?

Tags: angular, svg, fonts

I have a front-end project and my website have a lot of icons. I use some sites to convert svg icons to font, so that I can use them in my code. But, I have many problems with those sites and when I add new icons, everythings change and I should rename icons again.

I want a solution for converting svg to font in angular and I think it will make my work so easier.

Anyone knows how I should do this?